# Music lags/ hiccups when I seek using any Banshee or Rhthmbox

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox, gstreamer, flac

I have been using Linux for years now and this has never been a problem. but on my latest system [Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome Classic Session] It has been.. hiccuping is the best I can describe it.

It happens whenever I seek on any music player. I click anywhere on the seek bar and it will play, then hiccup back about 1-2 sec and play normally. I seek a lot when using my computer so this is ruining my entire experience. I have searched and searched but have found nothing.

my library is mp3 files btw.

Any help would be appreciated..

It worked fine on this system about a month ago.